# Is the Batman who Laughs storyline in "Dark Nights Metal" part of its own story?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, dark-nights-metal

So, I am going through the *[Dark Nights: Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Nights:_Metal)* story line currently and each of the nightmare Batmen has a one shot comic book related to showing who they were in their own negative universe before coming to our multiverse (or the Rebirth multiverse). But, the Batman who Laughs has more than one issue; the Batman who Laughs has a whole separate storyline.

Is that storyline inside the *Dark Nights: Metal* storyline?

I found the following reading order found [here](https://medium.com/@justinbeeson/dark-nights-metal-reading-order-1171cb24868d)

1. Dark Days: The Forge #1
2. Dark Days: The Casting #1
3. Dark Nights: Metal #1
4. Dark Nights: Metal #2
5. Teen Titans #12 | Gotham Resistance Part 1
6. Nightwing #29 | Gotham Resistance Part 2
7. Batman: The Red Death #1
8. Batman: The Murder Machine #1
9. Batman: The Dawnbreaker #1
10. Batman: The Drowned #1
11. Suicide Squad #26 | Gotham Resistance Part 3
12. Green Arrow #32 | Gotham Resistance Part 4
13. Batman: The Merciless #1
14. Dark Nights: Metal #3
15. The Flash #33 | Bats Out of Hell Part 1
16. Justice League #32 | Bats Out of Hell Part 2
17. Batman: The Devastator #1
18. Hal Jordan and the Green Lantern Corps #32 | Bats Out of Hell Part 3
19. Justice League #33 | Bats Out of Hell Part 4
20. Batman Lost #1
21. The Batman Who Laughs #1
22. Dark Nights: Metal #4
23. Hawkman Found #1
24. Dark Nights: Metal #5
25. Dark Knights Rising: The Wild Hunt #1
26. Dark Nights: Metal #6

According to this, I need to read *The Batman Who Laughs* after *Batman Lost*.
Is that the same as reading the first issue of the *The Batman Who Laughs* seven issue series or is a separate one from *Dark Nights Metal*? 
Wherever I look to buy a *The Batman Who Laughs* comic book I find issues from the series.

Comment: I think I answered your central question about which issue "The Batman Who Laughs #1" would refer to. If I answered the wrong question, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are essentially two *The Batman Who Laughs* first issues

The first is a "tie-in" comic to *Dark Knights: Metal*, *[The Batman Who Laughs](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Batman_Who_Laughs_Vol_1_1)*. It starts with the Batman who Laughs and tells his history. The second is the first of seven issues in the *Dark Knights: Metal* storyline, *[The Batman Who Laughs](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Batman_Who_Laughs_Vol_2_1)*, where the regular Batman is introduced to the Batman who Laughs through the seeming death of the Joker.

Based on context, I suspect they are referring to the first of the seven issue series.